# Form .post with jquery response returning same page

Tags: php, .htaccess, jquery

Trying to post a form with jquery and the response data is the html from the current page, not the url specified in the function.

```
<form name="vote_form" class="vote_form" action="vote.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="2056" />
    <input type="submit" name="up" id="up" value="Vote Up" />
    <input type="submit" name="down" id="down" value="Vote Down" /> 
</form>
```

Here's the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".vote_form").submit(function() { return false; });
$("#up, #down").click(function(event) {
    $form = $(this).parent("form");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ $(this).attr("name"), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    }); 
});
```

For reference if there is an issue here, the .htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler php-cgi .php .html .htm .xml
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.cgi

<FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</FilesMatch>

#Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I read one question here with a similar issue fixed changing URL PROTOCOL from AUTO to URI_REQUEST but I am not using CodeIgnitor or any other framework.

I've basically stripped everything from the page and just using the form and jquery above (vote.php only prints out the $_POST variables - tried with $_REQUEST also).

Basically I'm stumped.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried `alert( $form.attr("action") )` just to be sure you are getting the right thing? And also going to vote.php with your browser?

Comment: I didn't - was trying it with alert($(this).attr("name")); and it was working for the click event.  Then your comment got me thinking to replace the $form variable with $(".vote_form") in the .post and it worked just fine!  Thanks, man.  Fresh pair of eyes goes a long way!